# Android Browser-Like Reload "Swipe" - WebView

Tags: android, webview, reload

I made a little app for my fediverse instance and used a "template" from GitHub for it. Sadly it doesn't come with a Reload Button or a "Reload-Swipe" (like this one from Microsoft Edge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR6Q1.jpg)

How could I make a Reload-Swipe like this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.